# How do you obtain the Poké Flute to wake up Snorlax in FireRed?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I'm trying to get past a Snorlax and I need a Poké Flute to wake him up—how do I get one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the top of the pokemon tower in lavender town and beat team rocket and then Mr. Fuji will give you the poke flute. Then use it on the snorlax and catch it.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to obtain the Silph Scope from the Rocket Hideout in Saffron City.

Then you must travel to the Lavender town Pokemon tower and scale your way to the top.

After defeating Marowak you will have to fight through a few Rocket Grunts, and then Mr. Fuji will give you the Pokeflute as thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You will need the Silph Scope first. Go to the Team Rocket hideout (Celadon City) and best the Team Rocket leader. Then go to Lavender City, into the tower and make your way to the top. Beat a few grunts then Mr Fugi will give you the Pokeflute as thanks.

Then you can go to the Snorlax and battle him.

Answer (score 1):

You need to defeat a team rocket person and someone will give you it. You can use it to wake up Snorlax from the road and catch it.